# How to replace derivatives of a function with symbolic symbols and numbers with a replacement rule? (I.e. U'' maps to u2)

Tags: replacement

Suppose I have the expression:

```
expr = U''[x] + U'[x]
```

I would like to be able to write an abstract replacement rule so that I can transform the above expression to:

```
u2 + u1
```

I was hoping that the replacement rule:

```
U''[x] + U'[x] /. Derivative[n_][U][x]->StringJoin["u",ToString[n]]
```

would work. However, this disappointingly uses a literal `n`, and not a variable `n`:

```
U''[x] + U'[x] /. Derivative[n_][U][x]->StringJoin["u",ToString[n]]
(* 2 un *)
```

I suspect I'm close with my solution and I need to use some kind of `#` and `&` method but I still do not fully understand those functions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `(dexpr = U''[x] + U'[x]) // FullForm` and try: `dexpr /. Derivative[x_][f_][v_] :> 
  ToLowerCase@ToString[f] <> ToString[x]`

Comment: @Syed ah yes that works. I always forget about the delayed replace. Using `:>` in my example also makes the replacement works as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally easier to deal with indexed variables and to format them for display in any desired manner.

```
expr = U''[x] + U'[x] + U[x];

Format[u[n_]] := Row[{u, n}]

expr2 = expr /. {Derivative[n_][U][_] :> u[n], U[_] :> u[0]}
```

[image]

Or,

```
Format[u[n_]] := Subscript[u, n]

expr2
```

[image]

Reversing the replacements

```
expr2 /. u[n_] :> Derivative[n][U][x]
```

[image]

Comment: Whoops, sorry I have no idea why I did not accept this nearly a year ago, but this was the perfect solution to my problem.